# HBASE multiple values for single timestamp, timeseries data

Tags: hbase, time-series, bigdata

I would like to save multiple x-,y-,z-pairs with one single timestamp.

I measure 10.000 pairs in 10 seconds but have only one single timestamp  made at the beginning of the measurement.
Now i would like to be able to query a measurement on a specific time and access the x-, y- , z- pairs in Hbase.
I always need to access a column with x or y or z.

How should this be possible, do i need to use the timestamp multiple times? or should i just add 0,001 second to every pair and save timestamp +0.001 for every x,y,z pair?!(1000 pairs in 1 second, 1 pair 0,001 second)

Comment: You can specify the timestamp in the put statement, but I'm not sure that is the best approach with timeseries data.  https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html#Put(byte[],%20long)

Comment: it all depends on how you want to access your data. do you need all these pairs at once for specific timestamp?  or you may want to select only 400th X pair?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity.
only one single timestamp made at the beginning of the measurement  ..batchsize/timestamp details
query a measurement on a specific time.....queryKey details.
Also in case you have some problem regarding hbase query it is always good to mention details of your rowKey.

After this,you can expect better and quicker answer.